# MySQL > Pulling one of each ID from the database

Tags: mysql

So basically I have some taxonomies that are associated with relevant categories. The taxonomy relationship is defined in cat_1_id, cat_2_id, cat_3_id and so on. There are 5 possible categories.

I want to run one query that will allow me to pull three fields that contain each one of the categories. I know I can do this in three separate queries, but I want to keep it to one. Any ideas on how I can go about doing this?

My Query:

```
SELECT b.title, b.id, a.thumb_id, a.title, a.friendly_url, a.abstract
From `Article` a
JOIN `ArticleCategory` b
WHERE a.status='A' AND 
(a.cat_1_id = 1 OR a.cat_1_id = 2 OR a.cat_1_id = 3 
OR a.cat_2_id = 1 OR a.cat_2_id = 2 OR a.cat_2_id = 3 
OR a.cat_3_id = 1 OR a.cat_3_id = 2 OR a.cat_3_id = 3 
OR a.cat_4_id = 1     OR a.cat_4_id = 2 
OR a.cat_4_id = 3 OR a.cat_5_id = 1 
OR a.cat_5_id = 2 OR a.cat_5_id = 3) 
ORDER BY  a.publication_date DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the use case completely, but it sounds like you just need a lot of `OR (conditions)`.

Comment: Question is unclear. Can you provide sample data and desired result?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. But, you can rewrite your where statement to `WHERE a.STATUS='A' AND (a.cat_1_id BETWEEN 1 AND 3 OR a.cat_2_id BETWEEN 1 AND 3 OR a.cat_3_id BETWEEN 1 AND 3)`

Comment: I basically want to pull one of each category with one query